# White space error from url parameter

Tags: javascript, php, html

If there is two white spaces in a url parameter

http://localhost/auto/?supplier=AM%20%20K

Only one white space can be seen in php.That is getting AM K. 
How can I get the actual string?

Comment: I just tested here and `$_GET['supplier']` comes with a string with 5 characters, how are you getting that value?

Comment: yes, you are right.Thanks.
There is five characters in page source. Actually more than one white space will not display in browser.

Comment: So no problem here.  Move along.